# Invariants of objects in $D(\mathcal{A})$ for non-hereditary category $\mathcal{A}$

Tags: homology-cohomology, localization, derived-functors, derived-categories

$\newcommand\A{\mathcal{A}}$Let $\A$ be an additive category, and $D(\A)$ be its derived
category (i.e. the category of chain complexes of $\A$ localized
at quasi-isomorphisms). It is easy to show that if $X \simeq Y$
in $D(\A)$, then such equivalence induces a graded isomorphism on
their homologies $H(X) \simeq H(Y)$. Therefore, $H(-)$ is an
invariant for objects in $D(\A)$.

If $\A$ is abelian and hereditary (i.e. $\operatorname{Ext}_{\A}^2(-,-) \equiv 0$; e.g. the category of abelian groups), then any
bounded $X \in D(\A)$ is isomorphic to $H(X)$ in $\A$ (see
[1][2]). (The converse seems to be true as well, according to [1].)
Therefore, homology is a **complete invariant** in this case.

#### Question

How about if $\A$ is abelian but non-hereditary (say those with
$\operatorname{Ext}_{\A}^{3}(-,-) \equiv 0$ and so on)?

1. What are some examples of a pair of non-isomorphic objects that have graded-isomorphic homologies?
2. Are there other (complete) invariants?

#### Remark

I asked a similar but perhaps harder question ["Invariants of objects in $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathrm{Ab})$ up to chain homotopy" on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435414/invariants-of-objects-in-operatornamech-mathrmab-up-to-chain-homotopy) before localizing at the quasi-isomorphisms. Turned out that may be too hard, so I try my luck here.

#### Reference

- [1] https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1204064/562467
- [2] https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435414/invariants-of-objects-in-operatornamech-mathrmab-up-to-chain-homotopy

Comment: Although it would be fine with TeX's practice of ignoring whitespace, in MathJax you cannot separate your command definitions from the body by blank lines; doing so will force literal blank lines into the rendered post.  Unfortunately, though it makes the source ugly, it is necessary to put the `$` that ends the command definitions on the same line as the beginning of the body.  I have edited accordingly (also on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435414/invariants-of-objects-in-operatornamech-mathrmab-up-to-chain-homotopy)).

Answer (score 2):

**An example for the first question**

A simple way to construct an example for your first question is by truncating projective resolutions of objects, so in this answer I will assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is abelian and has enough projectives.  As an example, you could take $\mathcal{A}$ to be the module category over an algebra.

Assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is not hereditary.  Then there is an object in $\mathcal{A}$ of projective dimension at least $2$; let $M$ be such an object, and let
$$
\ldots \xrightarrow{f_3} P_2 \xrightarrow{f_2} P_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} P_0 \xrightarrow{f_0} M \to 0
$$
be a projective resolution of $M$.
Consider now the object $X$ in the derived category $D(\mathcal{A})$ given by the complex
$$
\ldots \to 0 \to P_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} P_0 \to 0 \to \ldots.
$$
Then the homology $H(X)$ is non-zero in degree 0 (since $H_0(X) \cong M$) and in degree 1 (otherwise $f_1$ would be injective and $M$ would have projective dimension at most 1).  Finally, consider the object $X'$ of $D(\mathcal{A})$ given by
$$
\ldots \to 0 \to H_1(X) \xrightarrow{0} M \to 0 \to \ldots.
$$
Then $X$ and $X'$ have isomorphic graded homology, but they are not isomorphic objects of $D(\mathcal{A})$.  To see that they are not isomorphic, one could note that, in $D(\mathcal{A})$, the functor $\operatorname{Ext}^2(X',-)$ does not vanish on $\mathcal{A}$ (since $M$ has projective dimension at least 2 and is a direct summand of $X'$) while $\operatorname{Ext}^2(X,-)$ does.